# PYQT use directory from one class on a script

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to run a script that takes the directory from a function in PYQT.  Right now it is set to using sys.argv and wanted it to be called such as

```
directory = createeditconvertorpage.selectFilecsvtoxml()
```

script1.py

```
directory = sys.argv[1]

print str(directory) + "this si string of directory"

def Main():
```

pyqtwindow.py

```
class createedditConvertorpage(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
def selectFilecsvtoxml(self):

    directoryPath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, caption="Pick a folder", directory=QtCore.QDir.currentPath())

    self.listDirPath.setText(directoryPath)

    for file_name in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        if not file_name.startswith("."):

            print (file_name) +  "   this is selectFilcestoxml"

    return directoryPath

def convertDirectory(self):

    import longXmlEditor
    longXmlEditor.Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class createedditConvertorpage(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    @staticmethod
    def browseFilecsvtoxml():
        directoryPath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Pick a folder", directory=QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
        return directoryPath


    def selectFilecsvtoxml(self):
        directoryPath = self.browseFilecsvtoxml()
        self.listDirPath.setText(directoryPath)

        for file_name in os.listdir(directoryPath):
            if not file_name.startswith("."):

                print (file_name) +  "   this is selectFilcestoxml"

        return directoryPath

    def convertDirectory(self):

        import longXmlEditor
        longXmlEditor.Main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dirpath = createedditConvertorpage.browseFilecsvtoxml()
    print dirpath
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this help, I just called inside the main but you can call from another script also. Make sure you have QApplication since it is using QtGui. Otherwise it will fail.